# Can the TS-570 be fully controlled over RCP-2?

Tags: kenwood, remote-control, ts570s

A fellow amateur here in VU-land reported the display on his 570 died.
Apparently the 570 has a proprietary computer interface called RCP-2 ;

- Are all features on the rig available on the RCP-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That software appears to mimic all the controls of the rig. As it is free, it's worth trying it out.

There is a useful list of alternatives here:

http://www.dxzone.com/catalog/Software/Radio_Control/